# The keyboard is dismissing instantly after being tapped on TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, textfield

I want to create a chat section in the app. That is why the top section of chat is displaying all the conversations and below is a TextFormField which is used to send messages.

Now whenever the TextField is tapped the keyboard is shown but it immediately is dismissed. Also I came to know that the initState in called when it is tapped (Got to know by using print(something) in initState), which has my stream. I have tried almost all the solution on internet as well as ChatGpt.

One thing is that when I comment out the section that displays the ListView.Builder

```
 // Expanded(
 //   child: _buildChatSection(),
 // ),
```

And then tap on the TextField it still dismisses it, so there is some problem in the TextField.

This is my complete code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../constants/constant.dart';
import '../../controller/controller.dart';
import '../../models/feed_model.dart';
import '../../service/FirebaseService/form_service.dart';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FormPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FormPage> createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  final messagesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Form');
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>? _streamSubscription;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> messages = [];

  FormService fs = FormService();

  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode focus = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamSubscription = messagesCollection
        .orderBy('createdDateTime')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          messages = snapshot.docs;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildChatSection() {
    return messages.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: text("No messages yet...", fontSize: Get.height * 0.03),
          )
        : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: messages.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                FeedModel model = fs.getFeedModel(messages[index]);
                bool isCurrentUser = model.uid == Controller.uid;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: isCurrentUser
                        ? Alignment.centerRight
                        : Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: isCurrentUser
                                ? accentColor
                                : primarySubtitleColor,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              text('~${model.name}'),
                              text(model.body!)
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: _buildChatSection(),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: textController,
              focusNode: focus,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: accentColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the debug console output when the error happens

```
D/InputMethodManager(26484): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{2a1a128 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2268 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(26484): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(26484): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
D/InsetsController(26484): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

`<application ... android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"> ... </application>`

in the AndroidManifest.xml file